# Highchart js click rotate and expand arc

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, pie-chart

Hi I'm looking to create a pie chart with highchart js that expands twolayers, and rotates to the center whenever I click a section.

So far I have a pie chart that expands one layer, and a click function that brings the arcs to the center (-90). I also have a click function that rotates the pie by degrees. My inner arc stays in the center and im having a hard time moving the arc to the same position of the out rings. The inner arc do not follow the click rotate aswell.

I would like to make a pie that rotates smoothly to center (-90) and expands with two extra layers. with the inner arch to follow the outer arch and be in the same starting point as the outer arch

Thank you in advance

here is what my code executes and looks like :

[pie chart with what im currently running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofCJU.jpg)

Here is my script

```
$(function () {

    var lastHighlight = -1;
    var lastPos = [10,10,10];
    $('#mouseMoveDiv').click(function () {
        var theChart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var currStartAngle = theChart.series[0].options.startAngle;
        //console.log('currStartAngle: ' + currStartAngle);
        var newStartAngle = currStartAngle + 5;
        if (newStartAngle > 359) {
            newStartAngle = 5;
        }
        //console.log(newStartAngle);
        theChart.series[0].update({
            startAngle: newStartAngle
        });
        var someData = theChart.series[0].data;
        var N = someData.length;
        var highLight = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++){
            var startAngle = someData[i].angle + (((someData[i].percentage/100) * 6.28318)/2);
            var dis = 1.5795 - startAngle;
            if (lastPos[i] > 0 && dis < 0){
                highLight = i;
                lastPos[i] = dis;
                break;
            }
            lastPos[i] = dis;
        }
        if (highLight != -1){
            var someRows = $('#dataTable tr');
            someRows.eq(lastHighlight).css('backgroundColor','white');
            someRows.eq(highLight).css('backgroundColor','yellow');
            lastHighlight = highLight;
        }
    });



    $('#container').highcharts({







        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}',
                    center: ["50%", "50%"],
                    connectorWidth: 0,
                    startAngle: 90,
                    animation: false
                }
            }
        },

        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },




        series: [{
            type: 'pie'
            data: [
                { name: 'Planning', y: 33.3 },
                { name: 'Sprints', y: 33.3 },
                { name: 'Release', y: 33.3 }
            ],

            size: '60%',
            innerSize: '40%',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        var chart = this.series.chart,
                                series = chart.series,
                                len = series.length,
                                index = this.x + 1,
                                i;
                        for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                            if (i === index) {
                                series[i].update({
                                    size: '100%',
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true
                                    }
                                }, false);
                            } else {
                                series[i].update({
                                    size: '0%',
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    }
                                }, false);
                            }
                        }
                        var points = this.series.points;
                        var startAngle = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                            var p = points[i];
                            if (p == this) {
                                break;
                            }
                            startAngle += (p.percentage / 100.0 * 360.0);
                        }
                        this.series.update({
                            startAngle: -startAngle + 90 - ((this.percentage / 100.0 * 360.0) / 2) // center at 180
                        })
                        chart.redraw();
                    }

                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                distance: 90, //distance name
                style: {
                    color: 'Black'
                },
                enabled: true
            },

            zIndex: 1
        },

            {
                zIndex: 0,
                type: 'pie',
                size: '60%',
                innerSize: '0%',


                data: [{
                    y: 2,
                    color: 'rgba(250,0,0,1)',
                    name: 'Training'

                },
                    {
                    y: 2,
                    color: 'rgba(250,0,0,1)',
                    name: 'Secure'
                },
                    {
                    y: 8,
                    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }

                }],
                dataLabels: {
                    distance: -30,
                    enabled: false,
                    style: {
                        color: 'black'
                    }
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            },


            {
                zIndex: 0,
                type: 'pie',
                size: '0%',
                data: [{
                    y: 3,
                    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 1,
                    color: 'rgba(0,200,0,1)',
                    name: 'test'
                }, {
                    y: 1,
                    color: 'rgba(0,200,0,1)',
                    name: 'test'
                }, {
                    y: 1,
                    color: 'rgba(0,200,0,1)',
                    name: 'test'
                }, {
                    y: 3,
                    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }],
                dataLabels: {
                    distance: -30,
                    enabled: false
                    style: {
                        color: 'black'
                    }
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            },


            {
                zIndex: 0,
                type: 'pie',
                size: '0%',
                data: [{
                    y: 6,
                    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 1,
                    color: 'rgba(0,0,200,1)',
                    name: 'test'
                }, {
                    y: 1,
                    color: 'rgba(0,0,200,1)',
                    name: 'test'
                }, {
                    y: 1,
                    color: 'rgba(0,0,200,1)',
                    name: 'test'
                }],
                dataLabels: {
                    distance: -30,
                    enabled: false,
                    style: {
                        color: 'black'
                    }
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you setup jsfiddle with your current work? I get something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nkukv1g4/4/ (with update on the bottom layer too in on click event). But I am not sure how click on "mouseMoveDiv" should work?

Comment: its this http://jsfiddle.net/vkhvvs5d/ , but I want to add another expand layer to the already expanded area. So for example, the red 11.1% needs to expand into 3 pieces. Then the next red needs to expand into three pieces also, so through and so on

Comment: Ok, so why don't you add more series and change `size` from 100% to 90% for a first level, and new series will have 100% instead?

Comment: Thank you, I cant figure our how to add more series - once I add the series the script doesnt add the extra layers

Comment: Because in your logic you assume that only one extra layer is possible. And you have `enableMousTracking: false`, so click event are not passed on to the callbacks. Anyway, I would use just three series, one per each level, and then manage visibility of the slices, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/vkhvvs5d/3/

Comment: Wow that is beautiful, thank you! Would it be possible to add a click function to each layer so that a text box appears on the side with some description for each layer? What functions would I call to rotate each layer to rotate to the center (3 o'clock) when clicked?

Comment: You already have click event, so I don't see any problem with creating there  function to show custom HTML element on top of the chart. And to rotate, update series with new [`startAngle`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.startAngle) param ;)

Comment: Thank you again, I updated the click function to show a text field when each layer is clicked. a question about the startAngle - is there anyway the startAngle can be slowed down instead of an immediate click and rotate (rotate to -90 within e.g. 3 seconds? )

Comment: The problem is that `series.update()` updates angle without animation. You can workaround this, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/8x54efu6/3/

Comment: I have tired the rotate, whenever I use the rotate with the expanded layers, the inside arch only rotates, not the outside arcs. Thank you

Comment: You need to rotate all layers (series), right? You're welcome :)

Comment: yes that is correct! also how can i give you rep or points for this? I really appreciate the help

Comment: Please do not deface your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change logic a bit: use one series for each of the circles, and manage manually visibility of the slices instead. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/vkhvvs5d/3/

And to answer the second question, rotate animation is not supported when using `series.update()`, however it have an easy workaround:  http://jsfiddle.net/8x54efu6/3

```
var chart = $("#container").highcharts(),
    pie = chart.series[0];

pie.options.startAngle = new_angle;
pie.isDirty = pie.isDirtyData = true;

chart.redraw();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to add this code to the click function of http://jsfiddle.net/vkhvvs5d/3/. Hopefully this will work

Comment: It will be very tricky - animation is strange for the second level of pie, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/vkhvvs5d/4/

Comment: Thank you this is great! I wanted to add if the slice is at -90 degrees, then stay else rotate to -90 degrees is this possible?

Comment: Feel free to modify `angle` in my snippet as you wish :)

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this, how would I modify angle to say " if angle = -90 dont rotate else rotate to -90"

Comment: `if(angle !== -90) { angle = -90 }` ? ;)

Comment: How could I keep `if(angle !== -90) { angle = -90 }` but then make sure the other slices will rotate to -90 if not at -90. http://jsfiddle.net/vkhvvs5d/5/

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. Maybe you misunderstood how `startAngle` works, please see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.startAngle).

Comment: I mean, when the slice is clicked rotate to -90 (like the fiddle above) in the above fiddle when the slice is clicked the other slices do not rotate when clicked. so e.g. when a slice is clicked rotate -90, then when the other slices are clicked rotate to -90. 

http://jsfiddle.net/vkhvvs5d/5/ this fiddle works for one slice but does not work for when the others are clicked

Comment: You need to calculate what `startAngle` should be. Setting it always to -90 won't work - because after second click, you already have -90 set, so what else would you expect?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot figure out how to modify the clicks. This is the last piece to this puzzle. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/vkhvvs5d/12/