# Highchart click rotate -90

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, rotation, pie-chart

When the slice is clicked rotate to -90, when this slice is clicked the other slices do not rotate when clicked. E.g. when a slice is clicked rotate -90, if the other slices are clicked rotate those slices to -90.

http://jsfiddle.net/vkhvvs5d/13/ this fiddle works for one slice but does not work for when the others are clicked

This is the statement Im trying to execute

```
if(angle !== -90) { angle = -90 };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rotate to -90"?  Do you want the pie slice that is clicked to start at -90deg whenever it is clicked?

Comment: This question comes from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554970/highchart-js-click-rotate-and-expand-arc/35938323).

Comment: Yes, I want the slice to be clicked then to rotate to -90, if its already clicked then dont rotate. Same goes for the other slices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to calculate what angle should be set. After each rotation startAngle will change, so option 1 - calculate it all. Option 2 - add a sum value for each point (you could parse your data before using it inHighcahrts, but in the example below I hard-coded it) and later on set proper angle based on point clicked.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/04y0pce2/

```
 // get angle
angle = 90 - (sum/total * 360) - (point.percentage/100 * 360)/2;
// 90 <- to what angle should point to
// sum/total * 360 <- what is total angle
// (point.percentage/100 * 360)/2 <- adjust to get middle of slice
```

For data as:

```
  data: [[1,0], [1,1], [1,2]],
  keys: ['y','sum'],
```

(`sum` is a sum of all previous points)

Comment: Thank you this is great. One question, is it possible for the rotate to -90 to affect all layers of the slice? For example, when the green slice is clicked the slice will move to -90, but when the layer 2 slices (the blue slices that expand from the green slice get clicked the whole slice moves back to its original position) I wanted each layer of the slice to be effected.

Comment: exactly like that! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the improvements! 

I was wonder if it is possible to make the second and third layer of the arc only have 2 expandable arc's for A and C.

But i want B to have three still

http://jsfiddle.net/cmpf2rtz/3/

Comment: @Max.H Yes, it's possible, but you would have to change some functions - pass how many slices in next level should be visible after click and prepare data in the next level in way that would match (in point y values) angle of clicked point.

Comment: Hi Kacper, This might not be the "proper" fix but I hacked something together. here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/cmpf2rtz/6/